# Requirejs plugin doesn't work with shim/deps/paths

Tags: javascript, plugins, requirejs, shim

I have a big problem with RequireJS. I wrote a plugin and the plugin is working well. It doesn't use `define` in it. When I use `requirejs(["myplugin!path..."]...` it works perfectly:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        "myplugin" : "path to plugin code ..."
    }
});
requirejs(["myplugin!path..."], function (something) {
    //works perfectly
});
```

So where is the problem? The problem is when I try to use requirejs config  such as:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        "myplugin" : "path to plugin code ...",
        "loadWithPlugin": "myplugin!path..."
    }
});
requirejs(["loadWithPlugin"], function (something) {
    //Ignores the plugin totaly...
});
```

In that way RequireJS ignores the plugin. Which means that I cannot use it with `shim` and `deps` nor `map` for different versions etc.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The `plugin!module` syntax is meaningful as a module name. However, the `paths` setting maps module names to *paths* and a path is not a module name. So if you put it as a value in `paths`, the text before the `!` won't be interpreted as a plugin.

You can use `map` instead. It maps module names to module names. Example that has `foo` resolve to `myPlugin!moduleA`:

```
  require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
      myPlugin: "lib/myPlugin",
    },
    map: {
      "*": {
        foo: "myPlugin!moduleA",
      },
    }
  });

  require(["foo"], function (q) {
     console.log("Q");
  });
```

Comment: 1st It's not working as you suggested. It accepts the plugin! only in direct url. This I think it takes the air out of the plugin balloon if you can use it only that way.

Comment: It is working as I suggested. I tested the code fully before posting here.

Comment: OK, it didn't work with map because I used version 2.0.2 instead of 2.2.0. Any way thanks,